# APNS Certificate is giving error when trying to upload it in cloud messaging section

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, push-notification-ios

My application is live on apple store.
I need to add push notifications in my app.
I have done all the required steps but when I am trying to upload ,.p12 certificate in APNS Certificate upload section in firebase console then I am getting the error message.

[You can see in snapshots.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Yy0.png)

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this issue, I cannot upload an APN, it says "There was an error reading your certificate" and its backend says INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot validate certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The issue has been fixed.](https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/a3WaERU17rvF7A4cXJz4)

I contacted the support and they were quick to fix the issue. I probably wasn't the only one getting in touch with them.

Answer (score 2):

Don't Copy Paste the keyId and TeamId :

Type it manually .....

Comment: Thank you, you save me. This is very strange bug...